# How to properly set privileges in page directory entries?

Tags: memory, x86, intel, paging, osdev

First of all: this question is about the IA-32 (x86) architecture.

I have a question about legacy (non-PSE, non-PAE) paging. In legacy paging, we have a page directory with 1024 entries, each one pointing to a page table. Each page tables contains 1024 entries (these are the pages), each one pointing to a 4096-byte aligned physical address.

Meanwhile, every single page directory entry and page table entry hold some flags, and both of them has an 'U' flag (bit #2): if this flag is set, then the page may be accessed by both user (ring3) and supervisor (ring0); if this flag is not set, however, only the supervisor (ring0) can access it. This flag is often called the "User/Supervisor bit".

The question: What should I do if I want to have both ring0 and ring3 pages in the same page table? I can set up the entries in the page table with the appropriate privileges, but what privilege should the corresponding page directory entry specify?

For example: I set up the first page table (virtual address range: 0x00000000 - 0x003FFFFF) to map physical address range 0x00000000 - 0x003FFFFF (this covers 4 megabytes). The first megabyte (0x00000000 - 0x000FFFFF) should be only accessible by the supervisor (ring0), therefore, the "User/Supervisor bit" is cleared. The following three megabytes (0x00100000 - 0x003FFFFF) should be accessible by both user (ring3) and supervisor (ring0), therefore, the "User/Supervisor bit" is set.

This page table is pointed to by the first page directory entry. But the "User/Supervisor bit" for that page directory entry should be cleared (only supervisor) or set (both user and supervisor)? What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CPU will use the most restrictive privilege in either the Page Directory Entry (PDE) or the Page Table Entries (PTE). If a PDE has Supervisor privilege then all the page tables below it will have Supervisor privilege no matter what individual PTEs use. If a PDE has User privilege level then the protection level of the PTE determines the final privilege level.

This behaviour is defined in the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 3A](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/processors/pentium4/sb/25366821.pdf).

> **4.11.4 Combining Protection of Both Levels of Page Tables**
>
> For any one page, the protection attributes of its page-directory entry (first-level
> page table) may differ from those of its page-table entry (second-level page table).
> The processor checks the protection for a page in both its page-directory and the
> page-table entries. Table 4-3 shows the protection provided by the possible combinations of protection attributes when the WP flag is clear.

Table 4-3 appears as:

[image]

**Answer to the question**: If you want to have a mix of pages with User and Supervisor privilege under a particular PDE then set the PDE to User privilege and the PTEs accordingly (User or Supervisor).